# Mount multiple nfs4 on CentOS without sharing a parent directory

Tags: centos, nfs, nfs4

I want to share `/share/foo` and `/share/bar` etc via NFS on CentOS.

I ran into [this common problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/148921/mount-multiple-folders-with-nfs4-on-centos):

```
mount.nfs4: mounting 192.168.101.254:/share/foo failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
```

The solution seems to be to export the parent directory `/share` with `fsid=0` and then mount commands on the client use paths relateive to `/share`, i.e.

server exports file:

```
/share 192.160.0.0/16(rw,fsid=0)
/share/foo 192.160.0.0/16(ro)
/share/bar 192.160.0.0/16(ro)
```

client fstab:

```
192.168.101.254:/foo /share/foo nfs4 intr
```

But if I want to export this from the server:

```
/share/private 192.168.101.123(ro)
```

then won't this be available on machines other than `192.168.101.123` because many addresses have access to `/share` and its subdirectories?

If so, this is an unacceptable security hole. If not, what is my assurance that no client can access `/share/private` despite the fact that they can access `/share`?

In summary, I need the server to export `/share/foo`, `/share/bar`, and `/share/private` to *different* client machines over nfs4.

Comment: Maybe this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/894906/mount-only-sub-directory-in-nfs-export) will help in your situation?  I don't think you should have to export `/share` if you are only interested in mounting specific sub-directories on you clients.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to use bind mounts:  create a folder just for NFS exports:

```
mkdir /srv/nfs
```

and then add this to your /etc/fstab:

```
/share/foo  /srv/nfs/foo    none    defaults,bind    0  0
/share/foo  /srv/nfs/bar    none    defaults,bind    0  0
```

The /etc/exports is exactly the same, save with /share replaced by /srv/nfs.  Also be sure and assign unique fsid's to the foo and bar entries in /etc/exports.